# Iterate over a map with values as List in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Iterate over a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and convert to type `List<KeyPair>`. Any better way to do it in java 8 (Using streams).

Naive way:

```
final List<KeyPair> keyPairs = Lists.newArrayList();
 for (final Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            for (final String value : entry.getValue()) {
                keyPairs.add(new KeyPair()
                .withHashKey(value)
                .withRangeKey(entry.getKey()));
            }
   }
```

Comment: What problem are you having using streams?

Comment: What do you see as the issue with your current approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, iterate over the map entrySet and then you can use `flatMap` for list of value for the map key and create `KeyPair` with entry key and every value of list and collect as a list.

```
List<KeyPair> keyPairs = map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                              .stream()
                              .map(value -> new KeyPair()
                                               .withHashKey(value)
                                               .withRangeKey(entry.getKey())))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```